# unusual JSON.parse Parameter: JSON.parse(<?= data; ?>))

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

First, sorry if this is a newbie answer because i am just a newbie in coding.

I just curious about this json.parse method that i found in somewhere in the internet.

So the code is like this:

`var data = JSON.parse(<?= data; ?>);`

What I want to know is the parameter in JSON.parse ---> `(<?= data; ?>)` what it means?

because as far as I know the syntax of JSON.parse is `JSON.parse(text[, reviver])`

Thanks!

Comment: That would appear to be some form of server side injecting. So a value from the server injected and placed within that block so it can be serialized when the JS runs.

Comment: ^^ e.g., the `<?= data; ?>` part of that is not JavaScript, it's something handled (probably on the server before sending it to the client) that outputs a string that `JSON.parse` can parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a server-side processing language ([known as Plates](http://platesphp.com/simple-example/)), where `data` is a variable being passed to the HTML file from a server. It isn't native JavaScript; rather, it's server-side rendering of a variable in the client.

`<?= data; ?>` renders the full contents of the `data` variable at whatever point in time that variable is called. In your case, it is a JSON variable that is being parsed in client-side JavaScript. `<?= data; ?>` returns the contents of `data` in the form of a stringified JSON (e.g. `JSON.stringify(data)`), and you then use `JSON.parse()` on the output to make it a usable variable in your client-side JavaScript.

Comment: EJS syntax is of format <%= user %> but the question is regarding <?= data; ?>

Comment: I confused the two symbols, though the premise is the same. I removed the reference to EJS until I can figure out what the language actually is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: a quick Google search shows that this is a PHP template language called Plates. [See here](http://platesphp.com/templates/syntax/).

This looks like a template tag, which would evaluate the value of a variable and export it whenever the template is rendered. I can't be sure, but since, in general, templates use delimiters to denote different things, it would appear that that's what's going on here.

I would assume that this specific example is outputting a variable called `data` since it uses this opening delimiter: `<?=`, which, since it has the equal sign, usually denotes output. This is done before the page is rendered in a browser, and more importantly, before this particular script is run; therefore, what I would expect, is that when the template is rendered, data will resolve to some JSON string, and then when the script is run, that string will get parsed into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

`<?= data; ?>` should be a php variable and the whole thing will be replaced by a valid JSON sent from the server at the time of client side rendering.